# Client Certificate Details and Single Sign On using Tomcat6

Tags: jsf, tomcat6, single-sign-on

I am newbie in SSO but wanted to know how I can extract details of the client certificate and setup Tomcat for the same 
I know that setting the value className='org.apache.catalina.authenicator.SingleSignOn' is the setup for the Tomcat but want to know how to extract the certificate details.
I am using JSF1.2 environment for building my website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's stored as a request attribute. I can't tell from top of head under which attribute name. Just explore the request attribute map as you can obtain by [`ExternalContext#getRequestMap()`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#getRequestMap%28%29).